# Password Reset View not sending Email (Django 1.11)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i am using Django Build in

> PasswordResetView class.

i am using `Django File backend` in settings. i tried to reset password of an existing account and django returns a success but still no email is sent. 
Here is code for reference:

settings.py

```
 EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'sent_emails')
```

views.py

```
class MyPasswordReset(PasswordResetView):
email_template_name = 'email/forgot_password.html'
form_class = ForgotPassword
from_email = 'admin@crud.com'
success_url = reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')
```

form.py

```
class ForgotPassword(PasswordResetForm):
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs=
                            {'class': 'form-control', 'title': 'Enter Email', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
                         max_length=50, label=False, required=True,
                         )
```

Password Reset Email Template

email/forgot_password.html

```
you forgot your password!! Sample Email
```

Code for Complete reference:
https://github.com/deepak1725/basicCrud/tree/dk-signup/users

Comment: have you configured the email settings?

Comment: @Exprator all i did in settings.py is as i mentioned. what else needed..?

Comment: an email server to send the emails, which you need to mention the settings.py

Comment: @Exprator i am at local.. using `file backend`.  
Expected behavior is make *.log files in my folder `sent_emails` with email content in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After deep analysing i figured out, i was storing email in username's field in auth User table.

Hence on using built in reset password view , it queries by database on email field, and hence the email field is found empty. So, the result returned is null and therefore no email sending is processed.